# Is there any formula for computing the product of $(n+1)(n-1)(n-3)(n-5)...(n+1-2k)$

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to compute the product of $(n+1)(n-1)(n-3)(n-5)...(n+1-2n)$ in order to use the Stirling's formula to calculate, but I am stuck. Thanks!

[image]

I am a little bit confused now... should the last term of $w(n/2+1/2)$ be $(n+1-2n)$ or $(n+1-2k)$?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to estimate this product using Stirling's Formula?

Comment: When $n$ is odd the product has to be zero since $0$ is a factor so you only need to consider $n=2m$ even.

Comment: Oops yes I know that n should be even, but what's next. Is there any formula for it? Thanks

Comment: Try to take $n=2m$ and multiply by $2^m m!  = 2m\cdot (2m-2) \cdots 2$. Do a similar thing for the negative terms. You should get a pretty compact answer for the product.

Comment: multiplied by that, I'll get $(2m+1)!$ and after that I'll divide the whole thing by that and I'll get a formula. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Call the product $S$ then $S(2^m m!) = (2m+1)! (-1)(-3)\cdots (1-2m)$. Now you can do the same thing with the remaining terms and solve for $S$ in the end.

Comment: Smart! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's $2^mm!$$2^mm!$?

Comment: I get $(n+1)!n!/(16^nn!)^2$. Is this correct?

Comment: @J.doe just to make sure, is the final term in your multiplication supposed to be $(n+1-2n) = (1-n)$ or $(n+1-2k)$ for some constant $k$?

Comment: Oops it should be $(n+1-2k)$. How do I do that then?

Comment: hmm... if that's the case then WA gives the result $$(-2)^k (n+1) \left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)_k = \frac{(-2)^k (n+1) \Gamma(\frac{j-n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2})}$$ where $(a)_k$ is the Pochammer symbol, AKA rising factorial

Comment: What does that greek letter mean?

Comment: That Greek letter is the Gamma function. It is the extension of the factorial function to values other than integers; it's one of the most important non-elementary functions in all of mathematics, showing up everywhere.

Comment: it is also shifted by a factor of one, i.e. $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ for all whole numbers. Just use that definition to adjust Stirling's Approximation for the gamma function and you should have your answer... now to prove the statement above will take me a bit. I would guess the formula above simplies a bit

Comment: So for $\gamma((1-n)/2)= ((-n-1)/2)!$?

Comment: Note that when you adjust Stirling's Approximation you get that $\Gamma(z) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}} \left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z$

Comment: What are you using the letter $\gamma$ to represent?? Generally $\gamma(n)$ is the falling factorial. Also, where did you get this problem from? Is there a specific way you are supposed to solve this?

Comment: I've attached a photo in the question. I tried to solve $w(n/2+1/2)$ and I am stuck.

Comment: I presume this is a tie-in to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662164/using-stirlings-formula-to-calculate-ratio) question posted earlier?? Note that duplicating questions is frowned upon, and may lead to the closure of one of the questions. Again, is this for a class or for personal study? Context is important for knowing how to solve the problem, and this site is not for doing your homework.

Comment: I was just trying to clarify my question so I attached it. Anyways thank you. :)

Comment: You are welcome! I actually recommend leaving the picture there, it adds context. Now, I'm not sure if that post earlier was yours or not, but I would link to it anyway and just explain that this goes deeper into one aspect of that problem; this will make the question meet site guidelines. I'm more than anything just trying to make your question not get closed (I'm also working on an answer atm)

Comment: You are also working on an answer on this problem? Great I get to double check my answer then! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*While @alex.gordan beat me to a full proof that's simpler than mine functionally, I figured I would share the way I approached this problem!*

First note that $(a)_k = a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+k-1)$. Thus, 
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)_k  & = \left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1-n}{2}+1\right)\cdots\left(\frac{1-n}{2}+k\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1-n}{2}+\frac{2}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1-n}{2}+\frac{4}{2}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{1-n}{2}+\frac{2k-2}{2}\right)\\
& = \left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3-n}{2}\right)\left(\frac{5-n}{2}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{2k-1-n}{2}\right) \\& = \frac{(1-n)(3-n)(5-n)\cdots(2k-1-n)}{2^k}\end{align}$$
Let's now adjust this to fit your product. First let's remove the denominator
$$2^k\left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)_k =(1-n)(3-n)(5-n)\cdots(2k-1-n)$$
Now let's pull out $k$ negative signs to flip each term
$$2^k(-1)^k\left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)_k =(n-1)(n-3)(n-5)\cdots(n+1-2k)$$
Now we simplify the powers and multiply by $(n+1)$
$$(-2)^k(n+1)\left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)_k =(n+1)(n-1)(n-3)(n-5)\cdots(n+1-2k)$$
We now use the definition $(a)_k = \frac{\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(a)}$, let $n = 2m$, and transform this into
$$\frac{(-2)^k (n+1) \Gamma(\frac{2k+1-n}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2})}$$
$$=(-2)^k (n+1)\frac{\Gamma(k-m+1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2-m)}$$
Now using the fact that $\Gamma(z) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}} \left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z$ (known as Stirling's approximation)
$$\sim (-2)^k (n+1)\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{k-m+1/2}} \left(\frac{k-m+1/2}{e}\right)^{k-m+1/2}}{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{1/2-m}} \left(\frac{1/2-m}{e}\right)^{1/2-m}}$$
$$= \frac{(-2)^k (n+1)(k-m+1/2)}{e^k}\sqrt{\frac{1/2-m}{k-m+1/2}} \left(\frac{(k-m+1/2)}{(1/2-m)}\right)^{1/2-m}$$

Comment: I just edited the question and I am so stupid that I got it wrong earlier. Help plz?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the comment thread here is long, and may have answers. I didn't check.

For $n=2m$ even, and $k$ not so large that factors wander into negative territory, then you have:

$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}={}}(n+1)(n-1)\cdots(n+1-2k)\\
&=(2m+1)(2m-1)\cdots(2m+1-2k)\\
&=\frac{(2m+1)(2m)(2m-1)(2m-2)\cdots(2m+1-2k)(2m-2k)(2m-2k-1)(2m-2k-2)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1}{\left[(2m)(2m-2)\cdots(2m-2k)\right]\left[(2m-2k-1)(2m-2k-2)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1\right]}\\
&=\frac{(2m+1)!}{2^{k+1}\left[(m)(m-1)\cdots(m-k)\right]\left[(2m-2k-1)(2m-2k-2)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1\right]}\\
&=\frac{(2m+1)!}{2^{k+1}\left[(m)(m-1)\cdots(m-k)\right](2m-2k-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(2m+1)!(m-k-1)!}{2^{k+1}m!(2m-2k-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)!\left(\frac{n}{2}-k-1\right)!}{2^{k+1}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!\left(n-2k-1\right)!}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Note in the comments that the OP said the product is $(n+1)(n-1)\cdots(n+1-2k)$ for some constant $k$, not $(n+1)(n-1)\cdots(n+1-2n)$ as he originally wrote

Comment: Thank you but I actually got it wrong in the question. I am supposed to find the product of $(n+1)(n-1)(n-3)...(n+1-2k)$. Thanks for the answer tho!

Comment: OK, well I edited a bit then. And now it's only a partial answer for even $n$.

Comment: How am I supposed to apply the Stirling's formula to $(n/2-k-1)!$?

Comment: @J.doe You just do. If you have some version of Sterling's formula for $n!$, then put "$n/2-k-1$" everywhere that formula has "$n$".

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry that you might be correct before, it should be n instead of k. And I get $(n+1)!n!/((\sqrt2^nn/2)!)^2$. Is this the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a closed form formula for the finite product

> $$ p=2^n(1-n)\frac{ \Gamma( \frac{(3+n) }{2}) } {\Gamma( \frac{(3-n) }{2}) }. $$

Comment: for the product of $(n+1)(n-1)(n-3)...(1-n)$?

Comment: but I get $(n+1)!n!/((\sqrt2^nn/2)!)^2$

Comment: It seems you edited your post!  This answer corresponds to your question before editing!

Comment: Yes I get it, but can you check with my new answer? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any new formula for $(n+1)(n-1)(n-3)(n-5)...(n+1-2n)$?